# Is it 'seeing as' or 'seems'?

Tags: idioms, sense-verbs

A friend of mine just posted this status on Facebook:

> Decisions, decisions - schoolwork...watch olympics....schoolwork...watch olympics......?? Olympics is so going to win this dilemma haha especially SEEMS the gymnastics is on later!

I said surely she meant *seeing as,* not *seems,* (she's used this word in a similar way before). She replied:

> ‎'seems' is also grammatically correct - it is a synonym for 'because.' And 'seeing as' is actually an idiom and is no longer the preferred phraseology

Is she right?

Comment: It seems to me this may be a novel use of the word, seeing as how "seems" is not normally used for "because". Could you give some indication of age and location? (There are tags "American-English" and "British-English" for example)

Comment: 24, English but in New Zealand. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I have no idea how to remove or report posts...can someone get rid of the vulgar reply please.

Comment: Following on from Andrew's response: it seems that this is _so_ novel a usage that it doesn't even appear in the Urban Dictionary. The defence given by Rachel's friend seems to indicate that she is confusing the concepts or at least descriptors **idiom** (without which devices English would be far poorer) and **cliche** (sorry I can't supply the missing acute accent in this format). Whenever a person makes a claim along the lines of 'This is grammatically in/correct,' or 'This is the preferred phraseology,' I usually ask them for evidence to that effect from a more accepted authority.

Comment: @Rachel down-vote the reply and flag it as spam.

Comment: When you tell her that she was wrong, also tell her about her punctuation.

Comment: Having never used this site before I find it a little strange that people are able to edit my original post, and ironic that what is there now doesn't make sense grammatically i.e. 'When I asked her that she should have meant.'

Comment: Rachel: On EL&U, most of the edits are improvements. (Just yesterday, for example, someone corrected a spelling error of mine).  In this case, though, I agree that your question was edited in a way that made it more confusing, so I "rolled back" that edit.

Comment: @J.R- OP's orignal post doesn't read properly. There is nothing wrong with the my edit. For example, tenses are switched back and forth from past to present perfect.

Comment: @Rachel- What is grammatically wrong about "When I asked her that she should have meant"?

Comment: @Noah Your edit looks very strange. It appears to be written by a person whose primary language is not English. The original sentence was fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your friend is making two assertions; one seems unsubstantiated, and the other seems tenuous:

> (#1) The word 'seems' is a synonym for 'because'
>   (#2) 'Seeing as' is no longer a preferred phraseology

The first assertion should be easily verifiable using a dictionary.  However, after checking several on-line [dictionaries](http://www.wordnik.com/words/seem), even the OED, I was unable to find any evidence that 'seems' could be used as a conjunction, or that the word 'seems' has some secondary or tertiary meaning along the lines of *'for the reason that'*.  Perhaps she was confusing 'since' with 'seems', since 'since' *can* be used that way.

> Olympics is so going to win this dilemma haha especially **since** the gymnastics is on later!

As for assertion #2, it's hard to tell what "preferred phraseology" means; however, I did find [one dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/seeing-that) that mentioned 'seeing as' is a more *informal* form of 'seeing that'. And, using Google's Ngrams to look at the [trend line](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=especially%20seeing%20as,especially%20seeing%20that&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=2), you can see that *'seeing that'* is more often used than *'seeing as'* – but there's no evidence that the phrase is falling out of favor (in fact, it seems to be trending upward since 1990).  Perhaps more significantly, no instances of *'especially seems the'* were found.

[image]

I would say that you are right, and she is wrong – but I'd avoid gloating, especially if you wanted to remain friends.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, she is incorrect. Your vindication is at hand, for I, a stranger on the internet, will help you! :D

In all seriousness, she is very incorrect. The word "seems" is used to define an object based on, either because of or in spite of, previously existing information.

> #### For example
>
> It *seems* like bananas are tastier than I previously assumed.
> OR
> Especially because it *seems* like the gymnastics will be on later!

"Because" is used to define an objects current state of being in relation to the state of being of another object or due to a preexisting condition. Be and cause are combined, the operative portion being "cause", they come together to mean that something else is the cause.

> #### For Example
>
> This banana tastes bad *because* I don't like bananas.
> OR
> Especially **because** the gymnastics is on later!

"Seems" is also used to express suspicion.

> #### For Example
>
> Your friend is wrong, so it *seems*.

"Seeing as" would be a much more appropriate term, as it is, indeed, synonymous with "because". Also, you could use "considering", "when", or, perhaps, "because".

I hope this wasn't too long, and I sincerely hope this helps.